# How to get the item with max date value in a dictionary with mixed type values?

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, max

In the dictionary `a`:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = {"ID":3, "CITY":"ATLANTIS", "FOUNDATION":datetime(2014,10,12), "COLLAPSE":datetime(2010,10,12), "REGENERATE":datetime(2011,10,12)}
```

How would you get the value which has the oldest date in this dictionary (in this case `"COLLAPSE":datetime(2010,10,12)`)? Remember, not all values are of same data type.

Comment: You'd still use a key function; in this case you could use `datetime.datetime.max` as fallback if the value is not `datetime` object.

Comment: how would you bind an `if` condition to a max() method in `max(a.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted the earliest date, you want to use *`min()`*, not `max()` here; a datetime earlier in time sorts before another that is later.

You'd need to use a custom `key` callable here, and return `datetime.max` for any value that is not a `datetime` object to discount that key:

```
from datetime import datetime

min(a.iteritems(),
    key=lambda i: i[1] if isinstance(i[1], datetime) else datetime.max)
```

This returns both the key and the value.

To get just the key, use:

```
min(a, key=lambda k: a[k] if isinstance(a[k], datetime) else datetime.max)
```

and for just the value:

```
min(a.itervalues(),
    key=lambda v: v if isinstance(v, datetime) else datetime.max)
```

In all cases only the exact syntax to get the value to compare differs.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = {"ID":3, "CITY":"ATLANTIS", "FOUNDATION":datetime(2014,10,12), "COLLAPSE":datetime(2010,10,12), "REGENERATE":datetime(2011,10,12)}
>>> min(a.iteritems(),
...     key=lambda i: i[1] if isinstance(i[1], datetime) else datetime.max)
('COLLAPSE', datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 12, 0, 0))
>>> min(a, key=lambda k: a[k] if isinstance(a[k], datetime) else datetime.max)
'COLLAPSE'
>>> min(a.itervalues(),
...     key=lambda v: v if isinstance(v, datetime) else datetime.max)
datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 12, 0, 0)
```